# Why is the MDToolvar icon not showing on Android?(Kivy)

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am building a kivy based Android app. At the moment when I run the app on Linux the MDToolbar shows the menu icon without a problem. But when I build the app for Android with menu icon dosent show up. The lambda function works even if the icon is not presented.

Here is an [image](https://ibb.co/xg5VNDm) that shows the problem.

This is the kv code.

```
MDToolbar:
  id: mainToolbar
  title: "APP name"
  left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: navDrawer.set_state("open")]]
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix this by upgrading Kivy to version 2.0.0.